# Critter movement if/else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

So I'm trying to create a critter code for a bird. I'm having trouble with the movement though. So it moves 3 steps in a north direction, then moves 3 steps in east, then south 3 and then west 3. I am trying to create an if/else based on this fact but I'm having trouble constructing one that will account for the directional changes. I'm trying to solve what the if else would be based on this pattern:

step 1 ^ (direction)

step 2 ^

step 3 ^

step 4 >

step 5 >

step 6 >

step 7 V

step 8 V

step 9 V

step 10 <

step 11 <

step 12 <

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Bird extends Critter { 
length = 3;
step = 0;
Direction original = Direction.NORTH;
// method comment goes here
public Attack fight(String opponent) {
    if (opponent == %) {
  return Attack.ROAR;
  }else{
  return Attack.POUNCE;
  }
}

// method comment goes here
public Color getColor() {
    return Color.BLUE;
}

// method comment goes here
public String toString() {
    return "V";
}

public boolean eat() {
  return false;
}

public Direction getMove(){
  step++;
  if (step < length && ) {
     direction = original;
  } else if (step == length) {
     direction = Direction.EAST; 
  }
  return direction;
}
```

}

Comment: What type are `length` and `step`?  You don't declare their type anywhere.

Comment: What does `opponent == %` mean?

Comment: Also `step < length &&`? Perhaps you've had some text formatting issues?

Comment: You code isn't even syntactically correct.  Please post code that will at least compile.

Comment: I haven't decided what is on the other side of && so it won't compile yet. Opps they're ints i forgot to declare. and each critter has a string value. The critter ant has a string value = % so when the birds opponent ==% it's an ant and it uses a certain attack.

Comment: alright I made changes so it will compile

Comment: ++step;? Does it should be step++? And what does it mean opponent ==%?

Comment: @Error404 sorry typo. I'm trying to have it recognize another critter file I have created but I guess I did that wrong as well.

Comment: @ShermanHerman Try to correct your sintax errors and then maybe we could help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
assuming direction is an enum...

Direction direction = 0;
public Direction getMove(){
  ++step;
  if (step > length) {
     direction++;
     step = 0;
  }

  if(direction > 3)
  {
      direction = 0;
  }
  return direction;
}
```

Basically this implementation allows you to call the function getMove() without having to worry about what step out of the 12 you are on because it handles the direction switching by just swapping to the next direct after 'length' steps are completed.

If you needed to change to a different direction this could be accomplished using a switch.

Comment: add explanation to your answer.